# WPF animation freezes even if I use new Thread

Tags: wpf, multithreading, animation, freeze

I am facing a big issue : In my WPF app, the MainWindow contains a Border with a Loading Animation (storyboard). By default it's collapsed. I sometimes make it visible and collapsed when I load a lot of data or when I'm loading a new XAML screen.

First of all, I wasn't using Threading at all and the  animation where both freezing and appearing with lates.

Then I began to use Threading like this :

```
Messenger.StartAnimation();
var task = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(150);
                }).ContinueWith((a) =>
                {
                    // HERE Screen moving + large amount of data loaded with Entity Framework
                    Thread.Sleep(200);

                    Messenger.StopAnimation();
                }, CancellationToken.None, TaskContinuationOptions.NotOnFaulted, threadUIContext);
```

This time, the animation worked during 1 second and then it just freezed until all data and new displayed screen where loaded. A It's like the main thread blocks ALL threads.

I've tried to add Timer to Delay my `Messenger.StopAnimation()` to 3 seconds later. Even this will freeze my animation for 1 second when everything is being changed and loaded on my new screen and then my animation continues for 3 seconds.

I've tried `Dispatcher`, `BackgroundWorker` and met same problem that with previous code.

I've tried to put my animation on a popup and even on a new Window which was Transparent. Nothing to do, it always end up freezing for 1 second before stopping...

For info, I use `ObservableCollection` (I've tried with List, same problem) and I load different screens inside a `ContentControl` in my `MainWindow`.

I've watched the techdays video, Fast and Furious and I really wanted to get a smooth animation like on the video, but the freeze seems impossible to remove.

Comment: You do not give enough details to know for sure, but if you throw notifypropertychanged events to the views, these will be handled by the main thread. So if you use threads to do the work, but still notify of changes, the main thread will still handle these and be occupied by it.

Comment: What control(s) are you binding the ObservableCollection to?  And how are you binding?   If you don't bind does the problem go away?  I know the app is of no use without displaying the data.  This is to isolate if it is a rendering problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issues when loading 50+ small images in a simple collection view. I found out eventually, that the .NET Framework drawing the bitmaps to the screen is what ties up the main thread, and that I had absolutely no way of circumventing that. I tried putting all the elements in the view but slowly filling the collection which was bound to the view, but every time the observable collection got changed, the .NET Framework redrew all the images in the view, so this didn't help too.

I asked a Microsoft engineer about this, and he bluntly admitted that it's a problem in the .NET Framework that will have to be fixed by Microsoft in the future. A colleague of mine said you could circumvent the issue by drawing all pixels yourself with your own algorithms.

I imagine if you want to fix this you'll have to change the way your data gets displayed, although I canot help you with the solution.

Comment: You could fix this by using a WriteableBitmap, and drawing all the individual bitmaps in one large bitmap, and if one changes, change that part of the large bitmap only, and than add a dirtyrect for that specific region. The MainThread will only redraw the dirtyrect.

Comment: That's totally not about what the question asked. It's about the speed the .NET controls get updated. Also, I used controls for a reason (I also have buttons and a lot of other stuff besides each image), but that was only stating the situation I came across the .NET frameworks' limitation. But thanks for giving -1 to tell be that my problem context should have been different - while I still think my answer pretty much sums up the problem Fulg has stuck here.

Comment: I just commented about your problem (because I thought it might be helpful for you). I know my comment is not about the question. Therefore I did not -1, it's someone else who did that.

Comment: Yeah well, I guess stating that it's a problem of the .NET framework isn't the best approach for an answer. Getting the answer "it's a .NET problem" from the Microsoft engineer when I asked him about my question also made me want to shuffle out -1 to Microsoft.

Answer (score 0):

We have the same problem as Jack, with a ListView binding to an ObservableCollection. After lots of analysis we decided it was the process of sorting and grouping that was slow, not the query on the database. Finally we implemented a separate thread, but of course had to call the dispatcher for the sorting and grouping which put that long running operation back on the main UI thread - so that appears to have swamped our nice "Loading.." animation - which appears to the user to hang and be jerky - not what we wanted at all.... As Akku stated, I don't see a solution to this, other than changing the way the data is displayed.